# Convert columns from multiple dataframes to boolean

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert columns from multiple dataframes to boolean. 
What I have written to convert them is the following:

```
for i in range(0,4):
        df[i][['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4']].astype('bool')
```

However it does not convert anything. Not all the columns from the dataframes need to be converted to boolean, so I have selected above only those ones that need to be converted. 
When I print `df[1].dtypes` (but I get the same results also from the other dataframes), all the columns above are objects, not boolean.

Could you please tell me where the error is in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `.astype` returns a new object, and does not do the change in place. In order to perform the change, run:

```
for i in range(0,4):
    df[i][['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4']] = df[i][['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4']].astype('bool')
```